# Vue js How to use onChange with TomSelect

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, tom-select

Is there a way to use onChange with TomSelect ?

```
<TomSelect
            :disabled="disableForm"
              v-model="wareHouse.agent.id"
              :onChange="changeAgentData"
              class="w-full"
            >
              <option value="">No Agent</option>
              <template v-for="(business, indexKey) in company.agentCompanies">
                <option v-if="business.companyType.includes('Shipper')" :key="indexKey" :value="business.id">{{business.name}}</option>
              </template>
              
            </TomSelect>
```

This does nothing. `changeAgentData` doesn't fire.
i tried `@change` , `change`, `changed`

Comment: Is this `TomSelect` a custom component? Because I read the documentation and couldn't find any way to use this as a component with Vue. Also, try the `@onChange` syntax as well.

Comment: Have you tried https://tom-select.js.org/plugins/change-listener/..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sur about what is tomSelect, a custom component you have created or from a librairy.

But in every case, if you want `@change` work, you have to setup this event or the librairy need to have a trigger setup on this (see the documentation for this component you use in that case).

You can avoid this problem if you don't really understand, and use a watcher instead.
Your v-model use `wareHouse.agent.id`, so i think you want to do something if this property change.

```
watch: {
 'wareHouse.agent.id'(newId) {
   this.changeAgentData(newId)
 }
}
```

Every time a user select a new option, your v-model update the value and the watcher is called.
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Comment: yep watchers seem to be the only way to do it